# Why wont facebook connect work on this page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the user to login using their Facebook account on the page but for some reason the button on the page does nothing. What the heck am I doing wrong? Link: http://friendsconnect.org/Main.php.

Comment: According to the console (Chromium's Web Inspector) clicking on the 'connect with Facebook' button produces this error: "FB.login() called before calling FB.init()." I'd suggest switching those around (so you're *initialising* `FB` before *calling* the `.login()`).

Comment: do you know how I can do that? Do I move the javascript code below it?

Comment: Find out where `FB.init()` is being loaded/called, and then move that around so that it's called ahead of `FB.login()`, without examining your scripts I can't be sure where either of them are. Possibly you could post the JavaScript/jQuery click-handler for the 'Connect with Facebook' button? And whatever script(s) that click-handler calls..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting the `FB.init` call into my JavaScript console and then hitting the "connect" button got me the usual Facebook Connect window so you're probably having timing issues. Try changing your `FB.init` call to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        FB.init({appId: '168032083219061', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    });
</script>
```

That way it won't be called until everything is all set up. Also, you don't need all three of these:

```
<script src="http://friendsconnect.org/jquery_custom/jquery.curvycorners.source.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://friendsconnect.org/jquery_custom/jquery.curvycorners.packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://friendsconnect.org/jquery_custom/jquery.curvycorners.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You only need one of them, probably the `jquery.curvycorners.min.js` version.

Comment: @Pete: Any errors messages from IE? Is the updated page up at friendsconnect.org?